# Alfresco FTS searches

Tags: alfresco

Is there a way, using a FTS search, to limit the result list to specific model types?

Also, is there a way to group the results of a FTS search?
Example:

```
Node 1
  prop_A: ABC
  prop_B: 1/1/2013
  prop_C: this is some string description specific to node 1
  prop_D: 1

Node 2
  prop_A: ABC
  prop_B: 1/1/2013
  prop_C: this is some string description specific to node 2
  prop_D: 1

Node 3
  prop_A: DEF
  prop_B: 1/2/2013
  prop_C: this is some string description specific to node 3
  prop_D: 1
```

Can you create a query that returns just Node 1 and Node 3? Node 1 and Node 2 should be grouped together because of the same prop_A and prop_B property values.

I'm using the [javascript webscript search object](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/4.0_JavaScript_API#Search_API).

```
var queryDef =
{
    query: "=prop_A:ABC",
    language: "fts-alfresco",
    onerror: "exception"
};

try
{
    model.articles = [];
    var nodes = search.query( queryDef );
}
catch(e) {}
```

Comment: This should be no problem at all with lucene. What search are you using now? What search string?

Comment: We're using 4.2c community with Solr. I'd like to implement it in a javascript webscript.

Comment: Hmm, I've re-read your question. You want to group results by prop_A? (Well, prop_A + prop_B combo, actually)? You want to get two groups of results? THAT would not be possible out of the box, I think, I believe you'd have to play with something custom. Does the search examnple you included return what is expected (nodes 1 and 2)?

Comment: Yes, group the results by an property, such that node 1 and node 3 are returned in the results from a single query. The search example doesn't do that, of course. If I did have to the custom route, how would I go about doing that? The other way that has been suggested to me is to create a 'rollup' node that contains properties of node 1 & 2, and use it make the searching easier. But that seems silly to me.

Answer (score 1):

Two questions here:

"Is there a way, using a FTS search, to limit the result list to specific model types?"

use the TYPE:"cm:content" clause to narrow results by type.

For the grouping question, you should look for an example of the solr facet support in Alfresco and check if this fits your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Do you have any links I can check out? As you can probably tell, I'm a little new to this.

Comment: See here http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Whko3pazRXQ or here http://www.ixxus.com/blog/2012/10/solr-facets-alfresco-walkthrough